# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Any

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am newbie to Scala. I have this code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, DataType, AnyDataType}
..

val test = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Tables.value.getOrElse("db.code_tbls",collection.immutable.Map.empty[String, Any]).toList.seq).toDF("code","cde_desc").as[(String, String)]
```

Above line in my code is throwing  `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Any` error. I tried to make my test variable implicit also. But I still get the same error.

Also I tried changing `Any` to `String` in `.empty[String, Any]` code. But still the same error.

Comment: Could you please help in understanding your piece of code?

Comment: In my code Tables is the dataset variable which holds hive table data. If I am not able to get the data from my dataset I am using getOrElse here to get the table name and empty map which I converted into List type. Then I am converting to DF with schema as "code","cde_desc" of type String. Please let me know if I need to add more info.

Comment: Are you using Injellij? If yes then try invalidate cache and restart.

Comment: Yes. Tried but no luck. For time being I replaced collection.immutable.Map.empty[String, Any] with null. Its working now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try collection.immutable.Map[String, Any]()